# integer expression expected - on return value - bash

Tags: bash

Ive been using this script for some time and now all of a sudden its throwing this error on these lines:

```
if [[ "$ret" -eq 0 ]]; then
#
elif [[ "$ret" -eq 1 ]]; then

else
echo "blah"

# further down in script...

if [[ "$ret" -eq 2 ]]; then

elif [[ "$ret" -eq 3 ]]; then

else
echo "blah"
```

its continually stating:

```
 [: : integer expression expected
 [: : integer expression expected
 [: : integer expression expected
 [: : integer expression expected
```

I've tried other comparison variations like:

```
if [[ $ret -eq 0 ]]; then
```

but it still fails.

ret is returning exit codes like `0`, `1`, `2`, etc

What might i be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your code uses `[[`, your error messages specify `[`. These are two different commands; those error messages don't come from that code.

Comment: How did you confirm that `ret` is an integer? The error message suggests it isn't set at all. As an aside, don't use `[[` for arithmetic comparisons. Use `((` if you don't want to use POSIX `[`.

Comment: However, if it _were_ coming from that code, it would mean the `ret` variable was empty.

Comment: Because the code included in the question doesn't ever set `ret` to a valid value, we can't run it ourselves without changes and expect it to work, so it isn't a valid [mre].

Comment: Those error messages should be coming from somewhere else in the script, not from this part.

Comment: `$ret` is either empty or contains multiple values. Either run with `bash -x scriptname` or add an `echo "ret '$ret'"` right before your `if` statements and conditional. Either way will allow you to confirm what the value of `$ret` is before the line where the error occurs.